# Anyone run into issues updating Altiris Deployment Solution to SP2?

Tags: update, configuration-management

We're going to be updating our Altiris Deployment Solution (build 365) to SP2 (build 375) and wanted to know if any of you have done so yet.  Were there any issues or hiccups you came across?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problems at all.  Just applied SP3 last week and no problems to date.  If you follow the Altiris KB articles on how to upgrade everything will go fine and you should not encounter any issues.